# Filtering posts by multiple taxonomies

Tags: loop, ajax, taxonomy

I have a page on which I want to display all posts of a specific custom post type, let's call it "persons". I want to allow the user to filter all persons by multiple (!) taxonomies: age, city, profession, level of experience. The best way to do that would be via clicking checkboxes and getting the results immediately via ajax without any page reload.

I think this is something many Wordpress developers want to realize. Unfortunately, I have not found any suitable tutorial for achieving this. But it must be something easy to do for experienced WordPress developers...

Can anyone provide a code template for how to build a filter page for the custom post type described above?

I already know how to filter posts by just ONE taxonomy, by jQuery. This is the code I used so far:

```
<!-- PAGE TEMPLATE FOR OVERVIEW OF ALL POSTS OF CUSTOM POST TYPE "PERSONS" -->

        <!-- LIST OF ALL ENTRIES OF TAXONOMY "CITIES"  -->
        <div class="cities">

        <a href="#" id="all">All cities</a>             
        <?php
        // Get all terms of a taxonomy
        $taxonomy = 'cities';
        $terms = get_terms($taxonomy); 
        if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="<?php echo $term -> slug; ?>"><?php echo $term -> name; ?></a>
         <?php } endif; ?>

        </div>

        <!-- OUTPUT PERSONS -->

        <div class="overview_persons">

            <?php  
            $args= array(
                'post_type' => 'persons', 
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'meta_key' => 'zip',
                'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
            );
            query_posts($args);

            if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

                $post_terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( "fields" => "slugs" ) );
                $post_terms_space_separated = implode(" ", $post_terms);
                ?>

                <!-- output selected taxonomy value in class of person div -->
                <div class="person <?php echo $post_terms_space_separated; ?>">
                    <!-- description of person -->                          
                </div>                  

            <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); ?>

        </div>

<!-- MY JQUERY FOR FILTERING PERSONS VIA TAXONOMY "CITY" -->
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        // Click on a city 
        jQuery('a[data-target]').click(function() {
              jQuery('.person').show().not('.' + this.dataset.target).hide();

        });

        // Click on "All cities"
        jQuery('#all').click(function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              jQuery('.person').show();

        });

    });

</script>
```

This code works perfectly fine. But my new challenge is filtering persons by more than one taxonomy - not only by the city, but also by the age, profession and level of experience. How do I need to modify my code for achieving this? Achieving this by Ajax would be the preferrable way, of course.

Answer (score 4):

First off, you should be using [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) vs query_posts.

Have a look at the [Taxonomy Parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters).

Mainly `tax_query` and `relation`.

```
// Repost from link above
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'movie_genre',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array( 'action', 'comedy' )
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'actor',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array( 103, 115, 206 ),
                'operator' => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    );
```

<strike>OR, if you'd prefer to declare it after, within the loop, have a look at [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). You could run the loop again but this time check each post for the matching terms.</strike>

```
// NO LONGER WORKS, WORDPRESS HAS CHANGED THE ARRAY STRUCTURE OF get_the_terms() -- OCT 2015
   /* if( array_key_exists( 111, get_the_terms($post->ID,'age') ) &&  array_key_exists( 222, get_the_terms($post->ID,'city') ) ) { 
      // output the post
    } */
```

OR, you could just do it all in jQuery (for example) if you're already going to be loading every single post on the page anyways. You could output `data` attributes for each post containing the terms they are tagged with.

```
<!-- For example // Where 111 and 222 refers to the term id -->
<div class="person" data-age="id111" data-city="id222"></div>
```

And then simply `.hide()` the ones that don't match the selected terms to be filtered.